# Button Background using :before not showing unless content property has a value

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem... I have a button, nothing special, just a button like so

```
<button class="btn btn--error">
    Button Text
</button>
```

Now I wish to have a image besides my button text, I wish to do this using CSS rather than have an img tag in the button. So I use the `:before` pseudo element, here is my CSS (notice it is SCSS)

```
.btn {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;

  &:before {
    background: url("/assets/images/icons/svg/ic_add_24px.svg") no-repeat top left;
    background-size: contain;
    content: '';
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
  }
 }
```

the location of the image is correct however in the browser I see no background image...

[image]

However when I add to the `content` property to the `:before` pseudo element like so

```
&:before {
    background: url("/assets/images/icons/svg/ic_add_24px.svg") no-repeat top left;
    background-size: contain;
    content: '___';
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
  }
```

I can now see the background image!

[image]

How can I make it so that I can see the background image without having to put text in the content property? Any help and advice is appreciated.

Comment: does using `background-image: url("/assets/images/icons/svg/ic_add_24px.svg");` work? instead of just `background: url(...) ... ;`

Comment: Using `backgroud-image` doesn't work in either scenario . I tried that previously.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but using a non-breaking space may be an option. I found this but don't know if it will work: `content: "\00a0";`

Comment: That kinda works, seems like a hack and the image looks a little funny but it does show the image...

Comment: you cannot set height/width on inline element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/4n1e8ksw/4/

Adding inline-block to pseudoelement. pseudoelement are by defualt inline and width and height for them is 0 if they have no content.

```
.btn {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 30px;

  &:before {
    background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-512.png") no-repeat top left;
    background-size: contain;
    content: '';
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
 }
```

Comment: We have a winner!!! That works!